# Use model variable names dynamically in Razor C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model in which there are four variables, namely:
`Image1`, `Image2`, `Image3` and `Image4`

I am trying to put four `<img>` elements in the view using a for loop. The `src` attribute of these elements should be `src = "\Images\@Model.Image1"`, `src = "\Images\@Model.Image2"` and so on.

So, is there a way to do this inside the for loop ?

What I've now:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    <img src="\Images\@Model.ImagePath1" id="image@(i)" width="150px" height="100px" />
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Short answer is no (at least not with out using reflection). Loops are for iterating over collections. Why not just have one property `List<string> Images` and add the 4 paths to it.

Comment: @Shanid you need to add all the images into a list and loop the list in the view page

Comment: In the image html code don't use width and height. Using css style instead.

Comment: @StephenZeng, Okay, I'll change it. It's already showing error, like "not a valid value" !

Comment: @Reddy, I am trying in that way, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to change the Model class then in the view you can do this:

```
@{
    var images = new string[]
    {
        Model.Image1, Model.Image2, Model.Image3, Model.Image4,
    };
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<div>
    @foreach (var image in images)
    {
        <img src="\Images\@image" />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This one is good if the OP doesn't want to change his controller and model code. +1

Comment: Yep, I dont want to change the model. I'll try this now :)

Comment: @Shanid Please accept it as an answer if it works for you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here. You could:

My first choice would be to save them in a list

```
public class ViewVM 
{
    public List<string> ImageNames = new List<string>();
    public ViewVM()
    {
        ImageNames.Add("image1.png");
        ImageNames.Add("image2.png");
        ImageNames.Add("image3.png");
        ImageNames.Add("image4.png");
    }
}
```

Then in your View just do

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ImageNames.Length; i++) 
{
    <img src="\Images\@imageName" id="image@(i)" width="150px" height="100px"/>
}
```

If however, you want to avoid using a list, you could store all the images in an  array like so: `public string[] imageNames = { image1, image2, image3, image4 };`

And then in your view just loop over them in the same way.

Comment: Your answer have quotes problem and `i` is undefined.

Comment: @nbokmans,  I dont want to change the list. I'll try your second method now.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a view model for an image like so:

```
public class ImageData {
    public int ImageId {get;set;}
    public string Url {get;set;}
    public string Alt {get;set;}
}
```

I would then create a ViewModel for the page like so

```
public class PageData {
    public PageData(){
        Images = Images ?? new List<ImageData>();
    }

    // Some other other properties here if you want or need

    public List<ImageData> Images {get;set;}
}
```

In the view:

```
foreach (var image in @Model.Images) {
    <img src="\Images\@image.Url" id="@image.ImageId" width="150px" height="100px" />
}
```